# CSS: Percentage centering input with padding

Tags: html, css

HTML (part of a form):

```
    <div class="container">
        <a id="p1_icon"></a>                                
        <input id="p1" class="input" name="p1" type="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width:80%;
    margin-left:10%;
    margin-right:10%;  // Almost certainly unnecessary
    position:relative; // To allow the icon to be positioned in the input
}
.input {
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;  // The icon sits in the 30px padding-left.
    ... other styling
}
#p1_icon {
    @include sprite_index(20px, 20px, -1063px, -246px); // SASS to get the icon from the sprite
    position:absolute;
    top:9px;
    left:7px;              
}
```

The problem, of course, is that the padding on `.input` gets added to the 100% width, so it ends up being wider than the container (and so is therefore not centered).

How can I get the `input` to fill the container entirely? I can do it with JavaScript fine, but I'd like a mobile-friendly CSS solution if one exists. (Note: I need the container for the auto-generated error messages. I'd also like the container width to stay at 80% to match some other stuff.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `box-sizing: border-box` to the input:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/QAtuX/

```css
.input {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

More information:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#box-sizing
- http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing

Comment: Fantastic! I'd read about it a while ago but forgot :( Thanks for this and the `caniuse` link.